# How to Choose x and y axis in a Bubble Chart dc.js?

Tags: scale, dc.js, crossfilter, bubble-chart

I have an issue with the x and y axis in a bubble chart with dc.js.

A company has two properties : a Ytd (randomly) and a Ytdn1 (randomly). What is the logic to choose the right x and Y axis?

x axis is for me : Ytd - Ytdn1 and the Y axis is the variation.  Is there any better idea?

How to choose the right scales for both x and y?
What to do for better readability? Any ideas ?

```
    yearlyBubbleChart
        .width(1200)
        .height(400)
        .transitionDuration(1500)
        .margins({ top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40 })
        .dimension(yearlyDimension)       
        .group(yearlyPerformanceGroup)
        .colors(["#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb", "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0", "#225ea8", "#253494", "#081d58"])
        .colorDomain([-500, 500])

        .colorAccessor(function (d) {
            //  console.log("Color");  
            // console.log(d);
            return +d.value.variation;
        })
        .keyAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.absGain/500;
        })
        .valueAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.variation/2;
        }).radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.fluctuationPercentage;
        })
        .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.7)
        .x(d3.scale.linear())
        .y(d3.scale.linear())
        .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4000]))
                //##### Elastic Scaling


        .elasticY(true)
        .elasticX(true)

        .yAxisPadding(100)
        .xAxisPadding(100)

        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)

        .renderVerticalGridLines(true)

        .xAxisLabel('X')

        .yAxisLabel('Y')

        .renderLabel(true)
        .label(function (p) {
            return p.key; 
        })

        .renderTitle(true)
        .title(function (p) { 
            return [
                p.key,
                'Abs Gain: ' + p.value.absGain,
                'Variation: ' + p.value.variation + '%'

            ].join('\n');
        })

        .yAxis().tickFormat(function (v) {

            // console.log("Hethi el V mta3 e tick")
            //  console.log(v);
            return v + '%';
        });
dc.renderAll();
```

Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w8top6zj/

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes to the Code and I have got a better result.

```
yearlyBubbleChart
        .width(1200)
        .height(400)
        .transitionDuration(1500)
        .margins({ top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40 })
        .dimension(yearlyDimension)       
        .group(yearlyPerformanceGroup)
        .colors(["#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb", "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0", "#225ea8", "#253494", "#081d58"])
        .colorDomain([-500, 500])

        .colorAccessor(function (d) {
            //  console.log("Color");  
            // console.log(d);
            return +d.value.variation;
        })
        .keyAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.absGain;
        })
        .valueAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.variation;
        }).radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
            return p.value.fluctuationPercentage;
        })
        .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.7)
        .x(d3.scale.linear())
        .y(d3.scale.linear())
        .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4000]))
                //##### Elastic Scaling


        .elasticY(true)
        .elasticX(true)

        .yAxisPadding(100)
        .xAxisPadding(100)

        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)

        .renderVerticalGridLines(true)

        .xAxisLabel('X')

        .yAxisLabel('Y')

        .renderLabel(true)
        .label(function (p) {
            return p.key; 
        })

        .renderTitle(true)
        .title(function (p) { 
            return [
                p.key,
                'Abs Gain: ' + p.value.absGain,
                'Variation: ' + p.value.variation + '%'

            ].join('\n');
        })

        .yAxis().tickFormat(function (v) {

            // console.log("Hethi el V mta3 e tick")
            //  console.log(v);
            return v + '%';
        });
dc.renderAll();
```

Here is the : http://jsfiddle.net/n34gn7qg/

Now I only have issues with  the Min and Max , both extremities are not entirely shown. Why is that behavior ?

I told the Bubble Chart to use elasticX and elasticY to calculate each time the domain of values ( Ytd - Ytdn1 ).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing your .xAxisPadding(100) value?

Try something like 2000, that might work...

Comment: unfortunately... still the Same Problem

Comment: Hmm... try .elasticRadius(true)

Comment: Otherwise you might want to use .focus([min,max]) to define a domain that is beyond the parameters of what you see here... That should render the bubbles inside, but it would be a hack... 

You would have to get the domain and then add/subtract 2,000 or a larger number from the max/min.

Comment: This is https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/998 - the bubble size is not accounted for in the elastic. One workaround given in the issue is to remove the clipping boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Use elasticX(true) and elasticY(true) to get the perfect scale. The problem is borders, which hide circle with max and min values. 
To solve this problem, you can hide the clip path as considered [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/998#issuecomment-216927317).

```
bubbleChart
    ....             
    .x(d3.scale.linear())
    .y(d3.scale.linear())
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    ....
    .on('renderlet', function(chart, filter){
        chart.svg().select(".chart-body").attr("clip-path",null);
     });
```

You will get something like that :

[image: result]